# Get all the views intersecting by a line IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, line, intersection

I have a grid of small (30X30 size) UIViews & I am drawing a line over them by tapping two points on the screen as startpoint & endpoint by using the code below:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {244.0f/255.0f, 226.0f/255.0f, 119.0f/255.0f, 0.8};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
```

Tapping two points on screen & drawing a line is working fine but how do I get all the views intersected by the line? 
I want to get these views in the touches ended method.

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:alphabetView];
  UIView *touched = [alphabetView hitTest:pt withEvent:event];
  CGPoint p = touched.center;
  // code here to get view list.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try CGRectIntersectRect function & passed your line frame & view frame to it.

Comment: ok but how can i get the line frame ? And i have about 80 views on the screen & should i check all of them one by one? Could you please provide an example ?

Comment: do you have list of views in array, which you have created?

Comment: No i dont have the list of view in array, but all these views are added in a bigger view & marked with tag. i can find  all the views by using :  for (UIView *view in alphabetView.subviews) {
             // code to get tag here
         }

Comment: @x-men: It would be nice to know if my answer was of any use :-)

Comment: yes @Martin your answer was knowledgeful, thanx but i was looking for the code. I got busy with my project so i am replying late. I solved my problem another way by finding the center points of all the views by which the line is passing. Actually i already have the views of definite size so it was easy for me to find the views which came across the line .

Answer (score 1):

A line segment (from point A to point B) intersects a rectangle (the view frame) if:

1. the line segment intersects any of the the 4 rectangle sides, ***or***
2. both points A and B are inside the rectangle.

If the answer to both (1) and (2) is NO, then the line segment does not intersect the 
rectangle.

The function `checkLineIntersection` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301701/1187415) might
be useful to check for condition (1).

`CGRectContainsPoint()` can be used to check for condition (2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGContextPathContainsPoint()` to check whether your `CGPoint` is in the path of your line, it returns a boolean value. its reference can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: ok , but how do i check that which CGPoint to check? i dont have points list. As i am thinking , I need to get all the points in the line itself & then check if these points contained in my view or not. But i m not sure how do i get all the points in the line . But this would be a lengthy & slow process . There should be a faster way.

Comment: as you said you want these views in touches ended and you have CGPoint p.

Comment: i have CGPoint p for the start point And endpoint only.i don't have  all the points between the start & the end points